# Symfony/Psysh error: The process has been signaled with signal "11"

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, composer-php

I've been given a php project that uses Symfony and wanted to do something equivalent to Ruby's **binding.pry** in one of the views.  However, I keep getting the

**"The process has been signaled with signal "11"."** error

and the server goes down.  Just had a couple of questions on why this is happening...

1. Can I bind into views?
2. Am I referencing it correctly?  My code below

`require('../vendor/psy/psysh/bin/psysh');
  //Path via composer.json
 ?>`

Somewhere below where I want to bind...

`<?php
  eval(\Psy\sh());
 ?>`